# bootstrap Dual column form

Tags: forms, twitter-bootstrap-3, alignment

I'm new to bootstrap and trying to create a responsive form. On a large screen it should not take up the full screen but the fields should be split into two columns and centered, but on a small device the columns should take up the full width.
In my code below I get the form to look the way I want on a small device but on a larger one I want it to be with two columns for the input fields and center the columns. I would appreciate some help in setting up the structure so that I can add the remaining fields I need and finish the design.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Horizontal form</h2>


  <form class="form-horizontal">
  <div class="row row-centered">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-centered">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label col-sm-3" for="email">Email:</label>
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter email">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label col-sm-3" for="pwd">Password:</label>
      <div class="col-sm-4">          
        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwd" placeholder="Enter password">
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-centered">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label col-sm-3" for="email">Email:</label>
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter email">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label col-sm-3" for="pwd">Password:</label>
      <div class="col-sm-4">          
        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwd" placeholder="Enter password">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">        
      <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
        <div class="checkbox">
          <label><input type="checkbox"> Remember me</label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">        
      <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>

    </div>
  </form>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div class="container">
  <h2>Horizontal form</h2>


      <form class="form-horizontal">
      <div class="row row-centered">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-centered">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="control-label col-sm-3" for="email">Email:</label>
          <div class="col-sm-9">
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter email">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="control-label col-sm-3" for="pwd">Password:</label>
          <div class="col-sm-9">          
            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwd" placeholder="Enter password">
          </div>
        </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-centered">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="control-label col-sm-3" for="email">Email:</label>
          <div class="col-sm-9">
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter email">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="control-label col-sm-3" for="pwd">Password:</label>
          <div class="col-sm-9">          
            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwd" placeholder="Enter password">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">        
          <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
            <div class="checkbox">
              <label><input type="checkbox"> Remember me</label>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">        
          <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
          </div>
        </div>
        </div>

        </div>
      </form>

    </div>





 Fiddler link is https://jsfiddle.net/j6jLhtc7/1/
```

Comment: Thanks, Exactly what I wanted. Can you please highlight the changes you made. And any idea why when I use inspect element in chrome and check it with responsive it doesn't re align into one row when its narrow, but if i make the actual page smaller it does?

Comment: In 'form-group' class  you have to make 12 columns

Comment: Also, is it possible to limit the max width of the form, so that once it reaches a certain size it shouldent become any larger? I set <form class="form-horizontal" style="max-width:800px;"> but then it throws it off center.

Comment: Thanks for your help Tariq. I got my form up and running, the only issue I have is, I have a picklist of countries but i want to add the functionality of the one in this demo http://codepen.io/Rio517/pen/NPLbpP/ I added data-live-search="true" but its not working, also the drop down doesnt have the correct styling, I added the bootstrap-select.

Comment: 1-you have to you use 'container-fluid' instead of row-fluid and 2-use 'form-control' class in select dropdown

Answer (score 1):

Use column offsets like this..

Demo: http://www.codeply.com/go/5TpRVW4yim

```
<div class="container">
    <form class="form-horizontal">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1">
                <div class="row row-centered">
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-centered">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label col-sm-4" for="email">Email:</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-8">
                                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter email">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label col-sm-4" for="pwd">Password:</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-8">
                                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwd" placeholder="Enter password">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-centered">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label col-sm-4" for="email">Email:</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-8">
                                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter email">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label col-sm-4" for="pwd">Password:</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-8">
                                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwd" placeholder="Enter password">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-sm-offset-4 col-sm-6">
                                <div class="checkbox">
                                    <label>
                                        <input type="checkbox"> Remember me</label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-sm-offset-4 col-sm-6">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Demo: http://www.codeply.com/go/5TpRVW4yim